# The non-invasive way to Instrumentation

Tags: debugging, trace, instrumentation, systemtap

I'm trying to find a way to monitor `Process` by `hooking` it's function.

```
       [Process]                             [thirdparty]
       ...                  trigger callback
                            
pc --> myfunc(st *s, int b); ------------>   handle_myfunc_call(ctx) {
                                              st *s = (st*)ctx->rax;
                                              s->xxx //do some statistics
                                             }
                               return          
                              <--------
        ...
       [Process]                             [thirdparty]
```

I know the easiest way is using eBPF with uprobe. But I need another way which may work under old linux kernel like 3.10.

### USTD

Programmer needs to add a `hook` in source code which is not I want.

### uprobe

I'm familiar with writting kprobe with kernel mod. But after searching Google, I find most `uprobe` sample are like this

```
echo 'p:myfunc binaddr:offset %x0 %x1' > uprobe_events
cat /sys/kernel/tracing/trace_pipe
```

It seems that `uprobe` just print the log but not calling some callback

### systemtap

As far as i know `systemtap` is using `uprobe`(fix me) to attach user function, but I don't know the detail about how it works. It seems using `uprobe` like `systemtap` works for me.

### Utrace

deprecated

### Like gdb attach

Thirdparty run as the parent of `Process`
ptrace
Rewrite instructions (like gdb `break` command)
Capture singal
Access the register

I think it's not easy and `singal` may cost a lot CPU time...

Answer (score 0):

`uprobes` is indeed what you are looking for but it is extremely poorly documented (To the point you might think it doesn't even exist).

The usage you mentioned is just a nice userspace wrapping to allow you use `uprobes` without using the actual interface directly. The thing is that you already know that because you know `ebpf` lets you more than just logging.

If you wish to use it directly, you will need to load your own kernel module.

The only reference I found online was this [sample GitHub](https://github.com/kentaost/uprobes_sample/blob/master/uprobes_sample.c) project that I never tried myself but from my past experience it looks it might be enough.
If that doesn't help I would try to reverse-engineer the usage from the actual [c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/events/uprobes.c) & [h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/uprobes.h) source code.

Another, probably harder-to-use option, is [Detours](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours).
It is a library that allows you to instrument functions in other processes. The problem is that it is for windows. So, you might want to [search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=detours%20for%20linux) google for a Linux implementation.

Comment: I see now that title says - "None invasive" which makes the "detours" option not relevant